# Export DDP to MXD based on Raw_Input?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, data-driven-pages

I am running ArcGIS 10.2.2 Version 10.2.2.3552, using ArcMap.

I have searched and haven't found anything on this or if it is even possible.  I'm trying to add something to my script that allows the user to define what pages to export themselves, so if they export the maps each week and only need 3 or so pages, they can input this themselves.  I tried throwing something together but anything i throw in there isn't working.  i think this is as close as i get:

Can someone offer me a hint or a nudge if i am in the right direction?

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"E:\User Folders\Recreation.mxd")
ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages
pageNumbers = raw_input("Enter Page/s:")
for pageNum in pageNumbers:
    ddp.currentPageID = pageNum
    pageName = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.Name
    a = ddp.pageRow.getValue('COUNTY_NAM')
    b = ddp.pageRow.getValue('RECREATION')
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, r"E:\User Folders\PDFs\\" + a + " " + "(" + b + ")     "+".pdf", image_quality="FASTEST", resolution = "100")
del mxd
```

Its getting hung up on "The attribute currentPageID is not supported on this instance of DataDrivenPages - even though i have used it successfully in the past.

Comment: You might have realized by now that raw_input doesn't work in a tool. You can put the page numbers in as a script argument or run it on command line but you *cannot* use input or raw_input in ArcGis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the pageNum is an integer, and you need to split the input values. For this example, you'll need to enter the pages like 1, 2, 3 with spaces. Give this a try:

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("E:\\User Folders\\Recreation.mxd")
ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages

pageNumbers = raw_input("Enter Page/s: ")

for pageNum in pageNumbers.split(", "):
    ddp.currentPageID = int(pageNum)
    pageName = ddp.pageNameField.name

    a = ddp.pageRow.getValue("COUNTY_NAM")
    b = ddp.pageRow.getValue("RECREATION")

    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, "E:\\User Folders\\PDFs\\" + str(a) + " " + "(" + str(b) + ")" + ".pdf", image_quality="FASTEST", resolution="100")

del mxd
```

Also, you aren't using the pageName variable anywhere, so you can remove it.

Comment: you could use the string .replace method to remove spaces on pageNumbers first so it wouldn't matter if the user had spaces or not.  Then your split would just be pageNumbers.split(",").

Comment: Yeah, that would probably be best.

Comment: This worked great, thank you! Is there a way, using this script to export them all as well?

Comment: Isn't that what the ExportToPDF part is doing? Make sure that file path actually exists.